# Photos: "Updating Library..." is stuck, library seems bricked

Tags: macos, photos.app, monterey

I have a large Photos library stored on an external drive, created and last updated with my old laptop, so probably in Mojave or Catalina format.

I got a new laptop which is on Monterey.

On my new laptop today I alt+clicked on the Photos app to select my external library and load it in. I was not surprised to see this started an "Updating Library..." process.

This proceeded slowly until it got to 79% and then got stuck. After a couple of hours of this stuck-ness (no progress beyond 79%) I quit out of Photos.

Next time I opened Photos it starts updating the library again. This time it is stuck immediately, on 0%:
[image: Updating Library... 0% complete]

It's been like that on 0% another couple of hours, clearly going nowhere.

I found this article:
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/photos/pht6be18f93/5.0/mac

> If you experience problems with photos in a library, you can try to repair it.
>
> Press Option-Command and double-click the Photos icon in the Applications folder (or click the Photos icon in the Dock).
>
> In the Repair Library window, click Repair to rebuild your photo library.

But if I do that it just repairs the (empty) local library, not the external one that has all my photos.

Maybe I need to set that as the default library first?

I found this article:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204414

> 1. Quit the Photos app.
> 2. Hold down the Option key and open Photos. One of the photo libraries is already designated as YourLibraryName (System Photo Library).
> 3. Choose the library you want to designate as the System Photo Library.
> 4. After Photos opens the library, choose Photos > Preferences from the menu bar.
> 5. Click the General tab.
> 6. Click the Use as System Photo Library button.

But that's not going to work, because it goes straight into the stuck "Updating Library..." and the "Preferences" option in the menu is greyed out while updating.

So it seems like Photos has pretty much bricked itself and probably corrupted my library too.

Anyone got any ideas to get out of this mess and recover my photos?

Comment: Have you try doing a First Aid from Disk Utility on the external disk before retry open your Photo library ?

Comment: @Jean_JD I have not, I will try that

Comment: @Jean_JD thank you that seems to have helped... I reopened now after First Aid and it jumped back to 79% where it got stuck originally, now has progressed to 86%. Fingers crossed if I leave it it will complete now...

Comment: I've found that, depending on the size of your photo library, this process could take up to 48 hours to complete.  Personally, I've found it goes quickest when the system is plugged into power and left alone, ymmv.

Comment: @Anentropic Let's cross our fingers together ;-)

Comment: You could just restore your backup, you know.

Comment: @MarcWilson my backup would also need updating, not useful if it would get stuck again. Anyway, pleased to report that the update process finished this time and library working now

Comment: @Anentropic Explain to me again why keeping this important data in an opaque database is a good idea?  I assumed that the statement "and recover my photos" meant you weren't actually backing them up as Apple recommends.

Comment: @MarcWilson you can always "show package contents" on the Photos library and get to the jpeg files, but I wanted to be able to actually use the Photos app again

Comment: Which breaks down the moment you turn optimize on.

Comment: thank you for your helpful comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the resolution from the comments:

Running "First Aid" from the macos Disk Utility on the external disk where my library was stored seemed to fix the problem.

[image]

After running First Aid I opened Photos again, and this time the library update process was able to run to completion.