# Apple Photo's Library from Mojave to Monterey looks stuck on updating

Tags: mojave, photos, photos.app, monterey

I have a Mini Mac running on Mojave. On an external drive I have my Photo Library saved. I don't use iCloud for Photo's.

Now I have a MacBook Air too. Running on Monterey. From this MacBook Air I opened Photos holding the Option-button to be able to choose my Library-location on the external drive. It started updating and said **87%** done. It took a long time and the percentage done didn't seem to grow. I stopped the Photos app thinking something went wrong.

Because of thinking something went wrong I tried opening it again on my MiniMac Mojave. (Of course) It didn't work. Tried it with opening Photos holding down CMD+Option-buttons to be able to recover the Library. (Of course) This also didn't work.

Started it again on the MacBook Air Monterey and now it looks to be stuck on **0%**.... For now I keep it open and letting the Photos app running.

**Did anything go extremely wrong here? Can I do something to fix this?**

Comment: I found this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431752/photos-updating-library-is-stuck-library-seems-bricked/441273?noredirect=1#comment636474_441273  

It seems like this is a solution I could use. But now I don't know how to use Disk Utility and find my external harddrive. The Library is put in a directory on this disk. Just as well is this external harddrive used for Windows-stuff. Not software, just files.