# How to use Disk Utility on external harddrive - Photos Library is stuck at updating

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, photos.app

I'm having this problem: ([Apple Photo's Library from Mojave to Monterey looks stuck on updating](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441271/apple-photos-library-from-mojave-to-monterey-looks-stuck-on-updating)).

I came across this ([Photos: "Updating Library..." is stuck, library seems bricked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431752/photos-updating-library-is-stuck-library-seems-bricked/441273?noredirect=1#comment636474_441273)) and it exactly sounds like my problem. The only thing is: I don't know how to use Disk Utility.

The external harddrive I use, is used in a network. I use it to store Apple as well as Windows files. From every device I can access this drive (by login). Can I use Disk Utility to repair my Photos Library-file on my external harddrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you  have a drive that you think has a problem and it is only attached via network?

If so then **no you can't use disk utility** to repair a network device. Disk utility (and for that matter any disk repair utility) is strictly for drives plugged directly into a computer of some sort.

If this drive is plugged into a server of some sort you would need to run any disk repair utilities *on the server.*

If this disk is on a NAS then the NAS itself will have disk repair functions of some sort.

You may also be able to unplug the drive from the server/NAS and plug it into your Mac and (assuming it is a Mac-native filesystem) repair it there.

Comment: I’ll check if there’s a possibility to plug the drive (NAS) directly to my Mac.